# Spring Batch Conditional Flow - The second flow always goes into status FAILED

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have created a Spring Batch app and I'm struggling to implement a simple flow with a condition. Here's what I want to implement:

[image]

I tried to achieve this implementing the following code:

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
    return jobs.get(Constants.JOB_SIARD_FILES_PROCESSOR + new Date().getTime())
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(listener)
        .start(step1())
        .next(decider()).on("yes").to(step2345Flow())
        .end()
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Flow step2345Flow() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("yes_flow")
        .start(step2())
        .next(step3())
        .next(step4())
        .next(step5())
        .build();
}
```

When the condition is "yes" the flow is working just fine, but when the condition is "no" the flow always ends with an execution status "FAILED". I want it to be "COMPLETED" just like the first flow but without executing the steps 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Batch does not allow alternative branches in the flow to be implicit. In other words, you need an `on(...)` for each case.

Assuming `decider()` yields a proxied bean, it should work fine with

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
    return jobs.get(Constants.JOB_SIARD_FILES_PROCESSOR + new Date().getTime())
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(listener)
        .start(step1())
        .next(decider()).on("yes").to(step2345Flow())
        .from(decider()).on("no").end()
        .end()
        .build();
}
```

To cover really all cases, you can also use `on("*")` instead of `on("no")`.

Please also have a second look at the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/index-single.html#controllingStepFlow